# How to select count today and tomorrow data less than specific time group by day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like a table below. 
I want to select count and group by day.

But the data in 1 day will start counts at 7:00:00 until tomorrow at 6:59:59 (24hr.).

For example

Day 1 data between '2019/06/01 7:00:00' and '2019/06/02 06:59:59'

Day 2 data between '2019/06/02 7:00:00' and '2019/06/03 06:59:59'

How can I code the where condition?

`id |     create_date     |  judge  |
-----+---------------------+---------+
  1  | 2019-06-02 8:00:00  |   ok    |
  2  | 2019-06-02 9:00:00  |   ok    |
  3  | 2019-06-02 10:00:00 |   ok    |
  4  | 2019-06-02 11:00:00 |   ok    |
  5  | 2019-06-02 15:00:00 |   ok    |
  6  | 2019-06-03 4:00:00  |   ok    |
  7  | 2019-06-03 5:00:00  |   ok    |
  8  | 2019-06-03 8:00:00  |   ok    |
  9  | 2019-06-03 9:00:00  |   ok    |
 10  | 2019-06-03 9:00:00  |  fail   |`

I've tried below but the result is not as expected.

`SELECT COUNT(*),DAY(create_date)
FROM mytable
WHERE judge = 'ok' and MONTH(create_date) = '6' and YEAR(create_date) = '2019' and TIME(create_date) > '07:00:00'
 Group by DAY(create_date) order by DAY(create_date) ASC`

Expected results
 
 `COUNT(*)  |  DAY(create_date)   | 
-----------+---------------------+
     7     |         2           |  (from id 1 to 7)
     2     |         3           |  (from id 8 and 9)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subtract seven hours from each date, truncate them to show the date only and then group them:

```
SELECT   DATE(DATE_SUB(create_date, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)), COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
-- Where clause if you need it...
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(create_date, INTERVAL 7 HOUR))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract 7 hours for the aggregation and the date/time comparisons:

```
SELECT DATE(create_date - interval 7 hour) as dte, COUNT(*) 
FROM mytable
WHERE judge = 'ok' and 
      create_date >= '2019-06-01 07:00:00' AND
      create_date < '2019-07-01 07:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(create_date - interval 7 hour) 
ORDER BY dte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
CAST(DATE_SUB(create_date, INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AS DATE),
COUNT(*) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY CAST(DATE_SUB(create_date, INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AS DATE)
```